# Decode number of tokens and token contract address from msg.data (ERC-20)

Tags: solidity, erc-20, solidity-0.8.x, fallback-function, decoding

I have a smart contract with just a fallback function and some logic.

I want users to send their tokens directly to the smart contract to do some smart contract logic on receive.

I've implemented fallback function and smart contract now is able to receive ERC20 tokens, but i also want to track how much tokens user sent.

I thought that its possible to do via decoding of `msg.data` in fallback in the following way:

```
fallback() external payable {
        (sig, tokenAddress, amount) = abi.decode(msg.data, (bytes4, address, uint256));
    }
```

I tried different things but nothing works:

```
fallback() external payable {
        (tokenAddress, amount) = abi.decode(msg.data[4:], (address, uint256));
    }
```

Can't decode even selector, just for test:

```
fallback() external payable {
        sig = abi.decode(msg.data[:4], (bytes4));
    }
```

Is it possible to implement this decoding somehow? I'm not able to rush user and execute another functions, i need to receive ERC20 tokens only via direct send.

Comment: This is not possible with a normal erc20 contract, cause when u send a token to another smart contract then that smart contract is not invoked.. everything happen inside the erc20 contract. Check erc777 please that could be a solution

Comment: Like @MajdTL mentioned, you can't see the value of the sent tokens from your contract directly.  On the high level you will need to listen for the transfer(or the approve/transfer from) event(s) on the contract that the transferred tokens belong to and then trigger your logic.  And yeah ERC-777 seems like a solid solution.

Comment: i will research more about that, thank you!